# page running on localhost hut not on remote linux server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server

my code below in code section is running well in localhost(apache2), but on remote Server not responding and after time out says internal server error 500. Even i added error reporting bit nothing can be seen.

ThanX in advance

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
/*----------Code to filter data from the db server dynamically-------------*/
/*----------error reporting  Initialization-------------*/
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "graph";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    /*----------Creating Connection With DB // For left side graph(c\t)-------------*/
}

else 

{
    $query ="select id from batteryinfo order by id asc limit 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die("unable to connecr to server");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    $fid=$row['id'];
    $query ="select id from batteryinfo order by id desc limit 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die("unable to connecr to server");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    $lid=$row['id'];
    /*----------Query to select first and last inserted row id-------------*/

    $data = array();
    $count=0;
    while($fid<=$lid ) {
        $nid=$fid;
        $nid=$nid+1;
        $query = sprintf("SELECT current, soc, blockvoltage 
                          FROM batteryinfo AS fi 
                          WHERE id ='$nid' 
                            AND (SELECT round(current, 1) = round(fi.current, 1) 
                                || round(soc, 1) = round(fi.soc, 1) 
                                || round(blockvoltage, 3) = round(fi.blockvoltage, 3) 
                                FROM batteryinfo 
                                WHERE id ='$fid'
                                )
                        ");
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        /*----------Query to select current, soc, blockvoltage after stisfying condition-------------*/
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            $count++;
        }
        $fid=$fid+"1";
    }           
    $result -> close();
    $mysqli-> close();
    echo"Total".$count."End";
    print json_encode($data);
}
//////////////////////////////fid=first row, lid=last row, nid=fid+1 (next id )//////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

Comment: Does you remote linux server support PHP and/or MYSQL

Comment: Can you even see an echo "HELLO"; ?

Comment: Are all the database connection parameters really empty or was that you just you  not showing us those parameters

Comment: Yes it supports.

Comment: Just i removed those parameters those aren't empty

Comment: Hard to believe but running on localhost and displaying data in json format

Comment: 1) Confirming that the database actually exists on the remote server?
2) What does your error log say? (Apache, Nginx, etc)
3) Also, not to do with your issue at hand, rather than selecting first and last ID's, why not select them all and do a `foreach()`

Comment: is there .htaccess file in your website sometimes the problem from it

Comment: Yes data base does exists. Server log don't show any error. Yes i have .htaccess file at my server.

Comment: @Sandeep try to remove .htaccess file ,if the problem from this file you must edit it or edit appache settings in your server

Comment: Rest of my php pages are running well on this server. Problem is with this page only, i did not get the reson to remove the .htaccess file. Please tell me why to remove it.